# How to connect Ubuntu 16 on 80 port

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as server.

```
my@wwwui:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

The port is opened like this.

```
my@wwwui:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and apache is correctly started and get index.html.

```
my@wwwui:~$ wget localhost
--2017-08-11 22:13:29--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11321 (11K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

index.html.1                                  100%[=================================================================================================>]  11.06K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-08-11 22:13:29 (175 MB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [11321/11321]
```

However telnet is refused from my local computer.

```
mylocal$ telnet jp.mine.jp 80
Trying 133.242.***.***...
telnet: connect to address 133.242.***.***: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Is there any places to check???

Comment: what's the output of `netstat -anutp | grep :80`? I assume you will see apache listening only on localhost (127.0.0.1) and not on your 133.242.x.x IP. And either you are using two computers (not clear) or you obfuscated the above information incorrectly. With this I mean your output uses "my@wwwui" and "mylocal$" Please clarify.

Comment: `netstat -anutp | grep :80` shows `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -   `

Comment: @Zina thanks for reply, yes I am using two computer  my@wwwui is server and mylocal$ is my local computer(mac book pro)

Comment: for ports below 1024 you have to use `sudo` or execute as root

Comment: I have tried again with sudo . only `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2293/apache2`  line appears @Zina

Comment: ok. can you share the IPs of both computers? why are accessing by a name which resolves to a public IP? can you try with the firewall turned off?

Comment: Finally I found out , it is because of iptable settings. Tt is set by my server company by default. I thought i set ufw so, iptables is ignored, but it was wrong. THank you for your help @Zina

Comment: I am glad you resolved it and that I put you in the right direction :) and yes, running ufw will not disable iptables.